# In Gradle, can one get the calling project or task from a Groovy method?

Tags: gradle, groovy

```
// method in a library or in an "ext" property

void aMethod(Object arg) {

    // in some way determine the "self" "this" etc of the **caller** and determine if 
    // the caller is a project or task within a project and get the project or task.

    // I assume this would use some sort of Groovy capability in the Gradle context 

    File argFile = callingProject.file(arg) // expand file paths relative to callingProject
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should describe a little bit the background of your question to understand your requirements better.

Comment: You could pass the project as argument to that function.

Comment: Part of this is a general question which might involve a Groovy capability to get the "caller" from a receiving method.

Specifically for now I added an "ext" closure to the root task that I want to call from another task and inside that know what task and or project called it.  

The same would be true if I had a library in buildSrc and a method that was called by a task or project.

Part of this is first to do a quickie, then later if it is good, make the effort to put it in an optimized plugin.

Comment: and I do not want to explicitly pass in the project as an argument.  In general this is how do I get the calling object's context lets say in a similar way you can with Ruby.

Comment: in java you can't get instances of caller objects. gradle does not provide api like `get current project` from outer world. mind the comments #1, #2.

Comment: They could have it like using a per thread variable "current task" which would be maintained as the current task being executed from that you can get the project etc or a currentContext. It would be extremely useful for library calls,.null if outside any gradle block.